# Rank of product of matrices with non-full rank?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Assume we have a square $n \times n$ matrix $A$, and a tall matrix $B$ that is $n \times m$ (where $m<n$). Now assume that $A$ is non-full rank, and has rank $m$, while $B$ is $n \times m$ and has full rank $m$. Both have rank $m$.

Intuitively, I would guess that $AB$ has rank $m$ almost surely: $B$ takes an $m$ vector, maps it to a higher dimensional space, without losing information, and then $A$ projects that to an $m$ subspace. Intuitively, I would say thattThe only situation where this should lose information, is when $A$ maps exactly orthogonally to the subspace that $B$ maps to.

So only in that very special case would $AB$ have rank lower than $m$. Is this correct?

Comment: almost surely is a technical term you really don't want to use here.

Comment: Okay maybe you do want to use almost surely, but the answer may depend on the distribution you assume of  the matrices and how big $n-m$ is

Comment: @N8tron so long as $n-m>0$ and your measure is nondegenerate, then what I said is correct no?

Comment: I don't think so what do you mean by non-degenerate? I'll add another case to my answer. I think this is very unlikely to be true in many cases.

Comment: I think we should also be clear. You are the one who should establish what measure you mean by a measure on $m\times n$ matrices (or on linear transformations from $k^n \to k^m$). Otherwise, I can invest quite a bit of time coming up with an example and then you can say that you meant something else.

Comment: @N8tron I mean this: let $M$ be the space of $m\times n$ matrices. Let $\Sigma$ be the borel sigma algebra on $M$. Then a nondegenerate measure on $M$ is a measure $\mu$ on the measurable space $(M, \Sigma)$, such that for any set $A\in \Sigma$, if we create for each matrix $a\in A$, the $n\cdot m$-tuple$v_a$ obtained by stacking the columns of $a$ and that tuple $v_a$ has lebesgue measure zero, then $A$ has measure $\mu(A)=0$

Comment: Okay i get the sigma algebra. What do you mean by the $nm$-tuple $v_a$ obtained by stacking the columns of $a$ ?

Comment: @N8tron e.g. if we have a two by two matrix $a$ with elements $x, y, z, w$, then $v_a$ is a 4 by 1 matrix with elements $x, y, z, w$. There must be a term for this.

Comment: That's called $\text{vec}(a)$ it's the vectorization of $a$

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the intersection of the kernel (or null space) of the linear transformation $x \to Ax$ and the image of the linear transformation $y \to By$.

Let's do a concrete example suppose $m=2$ and $n=3$. Define

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and 
$B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  \\ 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$

Note they both have rank 2. and 
$$AB
=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  \\ 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  \\ 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank 1

The bigger the difference between $m$ and $n$ the worse this effect can be If $n\ge 2m$ then it can be worse.

For example if $n=4$ and $m=2$

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0&0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0&0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ and 
$B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  \\ 0& 0 \\ 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$
both have rank 2 but theproduct $AB$ is the zero matrix.

---

**The almost surly arguments**

Lets look at the $m=1$ case then $B$ is a nonzero $n \times 1 $ matrix. It's possible that $AB$ could have rank one (be nonzero) but for that to happen the vector $B$ would need to be outside of the $(n-1)$ dimensional null space of $A$. Using the Lebesgue product measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ this set isn't contained in any open ball so I suppose you **could** say that it has measure zero.

Let's look at $m>1$ and $n>m$ then we want to know the does the null space $\text{Null}(A)$  of $A$ intersect the column space $\text{Col}(B)$ of $B$ in more than the zero vector. Both $\text{Null}(A)$ and $\text{Col}(B)$ have lebesgue measure zero as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So it's indeterminant what this would mean as a probability ($\frac00$ form).

Here's my attempt to try to make this problem a little more well-defined. Suppose that $A$ is $n\times m$ of rank $m$ then $A \sim \begin{bmatrix}I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ where $I_m$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix. In particular there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PA=\begin{bmatrix}I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Let's just pretend for now that a $n\times m$ matrix $B=[b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m]$ with i.i.d. coefficients will almost surly have rank $m$. If $AB$ has rank $m$ then $PAB$ will have rank $m$ for all invertible matrix $P$ so we can reduce the question to whats the probability that $\begin{bmatrix}I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}B$ has rank $m$ for a random $n\times m$ matrix $B$. Note the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}I_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is the projection matrix onto the subspace $H$ of the first $m$ coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So let $\hat{b}_1,\ldots, \hat{b}_m $ be the projection of the column vectors of $B$ into $H$. Then $PAB=[\hat{b}_1,\ldots, \hat{b}_m]=\begin{bmatrix}\hat{B}\\0\end{bmatrix}$ where $\hat B$ is an $m \times m$ matrix. If you believe $\hat B$ has i.i.d. components then the previous assumption would lead you to believe $\hat B$ almost surly has rank $m$ Therefore, $AB=P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{B}\\0\end{bmatrix}$ almost surly have rank $m$.

**Remaining Question:** Does $n\times m$ matrix $B$ with i.i.d. coefficients almost surly have rank $m$?

---

**Simulations**

I really didn't want to believe this so I simulated this in sage

```
N=10^5
n=100
m=3
K=QQ
A=block_diagonal_matrix(identity_matrix(K,m,m),zero_matrix(K,n-m,n-m))
count=0

for k in range(N):
    B=random_matrix(K,n,m,algorithm='echelonizable', rank=m)
    if rank(A*B)==m:
        count+=1
count/N
```

Here are my results for different $n$,$m$ and, $N=\#\text{trials}$ values
$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
N & n & m & \text{imperical probability}\\ \hline
10^5 & 5 & 3 & 99717/100000 \\
10^5 & 10 & 3 & 99542/100000 \\
10^5 & 100 & 3 & 99408/100000\\
\end{array}$$

I found these differences attributable to the pseudorandom nature of the radomization algorithm='echelonizable' in sage. Maybe it's not able to truly pick i.i.d. components. Though I may be wrong here.